# iOS asset sizes and design method

Tags: ios, swift, size, assets, portrait

The code for my first iOS 2D game is written. Now, when it comes to assets I feel lost. One reason is the feeling of imperfection due to outdated articles.
I need to know the image sizes, to begin designing. The device orientation of the game is **portrait** only. The status bar is hidden (game). The devices is universal, **primary iPhone but** I have of course no objections if the sizes are well with iPads too. What is the best image size to start designing for this intention?

If I did not have your help, I would have started creating the background (fullscreen) image at **1242 x 2208 and 401ppi**. Then, scale the final image down in Photoshop to **750 x 1334 (4,7“)** and to **640 x 1136 (4“)**. Am I right with my method? Especially, is it best to start with 1242 x 2208 or is 1080 x 1920 fine?

Comment: I would just scale down the final image, created at 1242 x 2208 and 401ppi. So it's the same image and does not vary based on the screen size. But I also don't know if there's a need to scale down or just add the 1242 x 2208 image to the @3x section and let iOS rescale it?

Answer (score 3):

**iPhone 5:**

**Display Size:** 4 in
**Screen Size:** 320 x 568 points
**Rendered Pixels:** 640 x 1136 (@2x)
**Pixels Per Inch (PPI):** 326
**Browser Size Portrait:** 320 x 460 px (320 x 528* / 320 x 548**)

**iPhone 6/7:**

**Display Size:** 4.7 in
**Screen Size:** 375 x 667 points
**Rendered Pixels:** 750 x 1334 (@2x)
**Pixels Per Inch (PPI):** 326
**Browser Size Portrait:** 375 x 559 px (375 x 627* / 375 x 647**)

**iPhone 6/7 Plus:**

**Display Size:** 5.5 in
**Screen Size:** 414 x 736 points
**Rendered Pixels:** 1242 x 2208 (@3x)
**Pixels Per Inch (PPI):** 401
**Browser Size Portrait:** 414 x 628 px(414 x 696* / 414 x 716**)

So I would go for the rendered pixels sizes for the images.

Comment: As a quick and dirty cheatsheet, also look here: http://iosres.com (as said, quick and dirty, only rely on this once you figured all out and are sure you know the general direction)

Comment: 2 days already and this answer isn't accepted? That's kind of unfair, there's really not much else to say... @rashwan-l should get the bounty (not that he needs the rep :) )

Comment: Rashwan L answered already, but You may also refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/).

Comment: The title of my question is "iOS asset sizes **and design method**", you answered only the asset sizes...an information that is easily googleable. You would go for the rendered pixels, so should I create a 1242x2208 image and scale it down to 750x1334 and 640x1136? And, if so, are these three images copied into the universal image set?